Flutter: Animator throwing exception
Icon should blink 3 times and then it should stop blinking. Icon should be visible after blink gets stopped
functioning properly and scheduler throwing exception after stopping

This exception was thrown in the context of a scheduler callback. When
the scheduler callback was registered (as opposed to when the
exception was thrown), this was the stack:

class MyBlinkingIcon extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyBlinkingIcon({super.key});

  @override
  MyBlinkingIconState createState() => MyBlinkingIconState();
}

class MyBlinkingIconState extends State<MyBlinkingIcon>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _animationController;
  int _counter = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _animationController =
    AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: const Duration(seconds: 1));
    _animationController.repeat(reverse: true);
    super.initState();
    _animationController.addStatusListener((status) {
      _counter++;
      if (_counter ==  4) {
        _animationController.stop();
      }
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _counter > 3 ?Assets.svgs.flame.svg() :FadeTransition(
      opacity: _animationController,
      child: Assets.svgs.flame.svg(),
    ) ;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}


import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyBlinkingIcon extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyBlinkingIcon({super.key});

  @override
  MyBlinkingIconState createState() => MyBlinkingIconState();
}

class MyBlinkingIconState extends State<MyBlinkingIcon>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _animationController;
  int _counter = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: const Duration(seconds: 1));

    _animationController.addStatusListener((status) {
      if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
        _animationController.reverse();
      } else if (status == AnimationStatus.dismissed) {
        _counter++;
        if (_counter >= 3) {
          _animationController.stop();
        } else {
          _animationController.forward();
        }
      }
    });

    _animationController.forward();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _counter >= 3
        ? Image.asset('assets/images/favourite.jpg')
        : FadeTransition(
      opacity: _animationController,
      child: Image.asset('assets/images/favourite.jpg'),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}


will check in morning and update you thanks for the answer

It is not blinking for 3 seconds

there was small bug i have fixed check it again just replace image url with your asset.

I have fixed the bug please check and leave a comment for me to help further in this code.

Did you check it again?

will check and update you
